# Android In-App Billing invalidKeySpecException wrong tag

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am implementing basic usage of android billing purchase v3 using IabHelper and I am still encountering this issue when I am testing on real device. I run the first time and after successful purchase i consume the product. Now I'am getting the error again and again.

I have already checked my public key (even using different encoding) so i don't think it is the problem. I have consumed all `android.test.*` products after testing static responses. I also tried to edit the `verifyPurchase` method in Security.java but it seems the error occurs at this call `PublicKey key = Security.generatePublicKey(base64PublicKey);`

Has somebody managed to solve definitely the issue?

Here is the log for the error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0890ba:ASN.1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:WRONG_TAG
                                                                          at com.hubsante.nutrition.utils.util.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:82)
                                                                          at com.hubsante.nutrition.utils.util.Security.verifyPurchase(Security.java:62)
                                                                          at com.hubsante.nutrition.utils.util.IabHelper.queryPurchases(IabHelper.java:972)
                                                                          at com.hubsante.nutrition.utils.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:624)
                                                                          at com.hubsante.nutrition.utils.util.IabHelper$2.run(IabHelper.java:698)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the var base64publickey length or format is invalid

Comment: Yes the format was not valid, i was not encoding in the right way. Thank you

Comment: @Leonald the way to say thank you is to mark the answer accepted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: How was the format not valid and how did you correct it? This would be useful info for others who have same issue.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the format of the public key was incorrect, i corrected it and now it's working.